# Looping over indexes of specific column(s)

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

Good day everyone

Take this dataset:

```
df <- tibble(
  id = 1:1000,
  smoking = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), length(id), prob = c(0.2,0.8), replace = TRUE),
  age = rnorm(length(id), mean = 60, sd = 10)
)
```

I want to add another logical variable `lung_cancer` to the dataframe where the `TRUE` or `FALSE` are assigned through probability distribution that is calculated based on the patients `smoking` and `age` status

I understand that this requires looping over each index, and I can manage to do it using `For()` loop so I wrote the following:

```
df$lung_cancer <- vector("logical", length(id))
for (i in seq_along(df$lung_cancer)) {
  df$lung_cancer[[i]] = if_else(df$age[[i]] > 50, case_when(
      df$age[[i]] > 50 & df$smoking[[i]] == TRUE ~ sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1, prob = c(0.05, 0.95)),
      df$age[[i]] > 50 & df$smoking[[i]] == FALSE ~ sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1, prob = c(0.001, 0.999))
    ), FALSE
  )
}
```

Now I find this to be too verbose, is there any concise way to write this with `mutate()` function and `purrr` package or any other way (preferably from `tidyverse` package collection)?

Comment: also I have another question that is unrelated to the title, but can I somehow adjust the `case_when()` function so that instead of `NA`, it return an specific value like `FALSE`?

Answer (score 1):

The `case_when()` function should be all you needed, but it does not seem to re-evaluating for each TRUE event.

Here is a simple base R solution taking advantage of R's vectorization ability (thus avoiding the loop).

```
#set all to the default value
df$lung_cancer<-FALSE

#perform the selections and then set to new value
df$lung_cancer[df$age > 50 & df$smoking == TRUE ] <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(df), prob = c(0.05, 0.95), replace = TRUE)[df$age > 50 & df$smoking == TRUE ]
df$lung_cancer[df$age > 50 & df$smoking == FALSE] <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(df), prob = c(0.001, 0.999), replace = TRUE)[df$age > 50 & df$smoking == FALSE]
```

*Case_when() question*
To define a default value with case_when, as your last test, define a TRUE statement.  Such as in this example:

```
case_when (
   df$age> 50 & df$smoking == TRUE ~ "Group1",
   df$age > 50 & df$smoking == FALSE ~ "Group2",
   TRUE ~ "Everyone Else"
)
```

See `?case_when` for more examples

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that this approach is still to verbose, I'm wondering if there is a way to do it through `dplyr` and `purr` since they are concise and pipe friendly. specially, it would be alot nicer to be able to preform all the mutations and variable creations within a single mutate() function. regarding the `case_when()`, there's a predicament associated with defining TRUE ~ argument. although I can use strings as you did, this argument doesn't accept logical vectors after `~`. later I can transform the character vectors into logical vectors but again it's not straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` allows you to mutate a portion of a column.  This way the samples can be generated only twice instead of 1000 times.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
df <- data.table(
  id = 1:1000,
  smoking = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), length(id), prob = c(0.2,0.8), replace = TRUE),
  age = rnorm(length(id), mean = 60, sd = 10)
) %>% 
  .[, lung_cancer := FALSE] %>% 
  .[age > 50 & smoking, lung_cancer := sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), .N, prob = c(0.05, 0.95), replace = TRUE)] %>% 
  .[age > 50 & !smoking, lung_cancer := sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), .N, prob = c(0.001, 0.999), replace = TRUE)] %>% 
  .[]
  
df[, .(.N, lc = sum(lung_cancer)), keyby = smoking]
   smoking   N lc
1:   FALSE 804  2
2:    TRUE 196  5
```

I put a "report" at the end.
(You can convert your tibble to a data.table with `setDT()` instead, if necessary)